# Best way to run WINE on OS X?

Tags: wine

What is it?

(I know, oh so subjective.)

So let's make that, what's the most effective and pain free way to do it? I realize those may be contradictory conditions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest and most pain free way is to use homebrew

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once you follow the instructions to install homebrew on this page (which include installing Xcode), you can then simply type

```
brew install wine
```

And this will download and compile wine and all its dependendencies.

Comment: Well, that gets you WINE. But I mean stuff like Wineskin and WineBottler. Tools that make WINE operation and configuration easier.

Comment: In terms of most effective and pain free - vanilla wine is the best and most up-to-date way.  WineBottler in particular seems pretty inactive.  Check out the Wine FAQ http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ   There isn't much configuration required, simply start an app with wine /path/to/app.exe

Comment: I followed the brew way but I got errors while trying to run applications, like complaining about missing common controls library, visual studio runtimes and so.

Comment: @robZolkos WineBottler seems to run stable wine, hence the infrequent updates. Still works like a charm though. (Except maybe winetricks)

Answer (score 6):

You can install wine using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) they both are recommended my wine.

As for GUI applications for wine the only thing besides wine's own utilities is [winetricks](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/). They are pretty useful for automatically downloading and installing different applications and dlls with their dependencies.

If your OSX is older than 10.5 than you will definitely need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) (newer version already include X server).

#### MacPorts

[Install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) at first.

Let's search packages matching 'wine':

```
port search wine
```

```
wine @1.4 (x11)
    Wine Is Not an Emulator

wine-crossover @11.0.0 (x11)
    Wine Is Not an Emulator (1.4-rc5 with CodeWeavers modifications for CrossOver)

wine-crossover-games @10.1.1 (x11)
    Wine Is Not an Emulator (1.3.9 with CodeWeavers modifications for CrossOver Games)

wine-devel @1.5.0 (x11)
    Wine Is Not an Emulator

winetricks @20120308 (x11)
    downloads and installs various redistributable runtime libraries
```

Now we see that we can either install CodeWeavers version or just usual wine. Let's install usual wine (I think that for another one you need some kind of licesce):

```
sudo port install wine
```

It's also a good idea to install winetricks:

```
sudo port install winetricks
```

#### Fink

Install Fink as deskribed [here](http://www.finkproject.org/doc/users-guide/install.php).

```
fink list wine
```

```
     wine                  1.3.21-1         Microsoft Windows compatibility layer
     wine-dev              1.3.21-1         Microsoft Windows compatibility layer
     winetricks            20111120-2       Install redistributable runtime tools in Wine
```

Let's now install them

```
fink install wine
fink install winetricks
```

#### After installation

In terminal enter wine and press [Tab] and you will see utiles that come with wine (and winetricks of course):

```
wine         winebuild    wineconsole  winedbg      winefile     winegcc      winemine     wineserver   
wineboot     winecfg      winecpp      winedump     wineg++      winemaker    winepath     winetricks
```

**winecfg** is very useful to configure wine (dlls overriding, Windows version selection, etc.)

---

Is also probably posible to install wine on top of Gentoo prefix, but I'm not sure that you will get X support in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using Winebottler from http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/ 
works fine for me!

Answer (score 4):

Most pain free way is to use Codeweavers's paid for version [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/)

It has useful default settings and for many apps provides C4P or CrossTie which will do all the installation and set up of the app from one script.

Answer (score 3):

The best graphical install of Wine is Wineskin. It puts all the tools in a GUI and creates a standalone .app file that Mac will run as a native app. Here is a tutorial that is using Steam as an example.

http://www.easypctutorials.com/windows-steam-on-mac-wineskin

If you plan on porting several applications then you'll want to run just one Wine environment. MacPorts or Homebrew are probably your best options.

http://www.easypctutorials.com/how-to-install-wine-on-mac-os-x

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help), especially the last paragraph in http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior